# Rail Add Password on Uploaded PDF file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, password-protection, password-encryption

I have an Rails application where the user can upload a PDF. The application will add a password automatically(the password will be generated using the user's data) then will save it to AWS S3. So, when the user opens that PDF, the PDF would ask for the password.

Right now I am able to upload the PDF without adding password and it is working. My problem is adding password on it automatically.

On the same application, I also used Prawn since I have separate feature where the system will generate the PDF(not upload by the user) and I can add password into it.

P.S. I also need to add password if the user upload an image file. I just want to ask if there is a way I can add password to uploaded image file OR I need to convert it to PDF?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi @KJ, sorry I didn't elaborate my question, I have modified it. Actually, the system will add the password, not the user. Once the student upload a PDF file, the application will add a password automatically(the password will be generated using the user's data) then will save it to AWS S3.

Comment: The PDF file uploaded by the user, will be view or can be download by the other user. If the PDF has a sensitive information, it can be seen by the other user and that is why I need to add the password on the PDF.